# Centered text or icon in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Trying to place an icon at the center of two boxes. Appreciate your help on this. Thanks.

Comment: set property on start element `position: absolute;
 left: 40%;` and `position:relative` on parent div

Comment: @Anilkumar I tried but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this uses bootstrap, it seems that class `position-relative` can be added to the container `div`, and `position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle` can be added for the icon.

Forked live demo on: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-icon-between-ef3btj?file=/src/App.tsx)

The posted codesandbox is using `reactstrap` but did not seem to install `bootstrap` as it requires, so the above example had the package installed.

*While the post is tagged with `bootstrap-4`, the installed version of `reactstrap` does not seem to support it, so this example had the new version of bootstrap installed. If `bootstrap-4` is needed, some class names may need to be replaced as custom CSS.*

A custom class is also added for the icon to add some higher `z-index`:

```
.custom-icon {
  z-index: 2500;
}
```

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Row, Col, Input } from "reactstrap";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <div className="input-group position-relative">
          <Input type="text" className="custom-input" placeholder="Origin" />
          <Input
            type="text"
            className="custom-input"
            placeholder="Destination"
          />
          <img
            src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1828/1828961.png"
            alt="icon"
            width="15"
            className="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle custom-icon"
          />
        </div>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

Comment: Beautifully done. . I am grateful to you. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> App.tsx

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <div className="input-group">
          <Input
            type="text"
            className="custom-input origin"
            placeholder="Origin"
          />
          <img
            src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1828/1828961.png"
            alt="star"
            width="15"
            className="star"
          />
          <Input
            type="text"
            className="custom-input destination"
            placeholder="Destination"
          />
        </div>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

> styles.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.input-group .custom-input {
  height: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.input-group .destination {
  position: absolute;
  left: 170px;
}

.star {
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  left: -8px;
}

.autocomplete {
  padding: 0px;
  background-size: 17px 15px;
  position: absolute;
}
```